# Select rows from SQL table and merge on those particular rows to another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I have 2 tables in SQL. In the publications table, I am only interested in some rows that have the IDs that I am interested in. I used this code to isolate the rows that I am interested in :

```
SELECT * FROM publications 
    WHERE publications.id IN (175428,547257,526852)
```

The second table has author demographics.

**The goal:**

I want to merge the rows that I am interested in from the publications table to the author table. I want to merge on author_id. I want all columns from the author table but only some columns from the publications table like "link"

**extra:**

Once I merge can I filter out the merged table by the country?

Example of Tables:

```
publications | ID| author_id| link|

tipping point|5  |124543    |www.tfjd.com

clink        |2  |674255    |www.tfjd.com
```

---

```
author_id|name            |country

124543   |Malcomn Gladwell|US

437821   |JK Rowling      |UK
```

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. What are you *really* using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following query:

```
SELECT
        a.*,
        p.link,
        p.publications
FROM
        Publications p
    JOIN
        Author       a
            ON p.ID = a.author_id
WHERE
        p.id IN (175428, 547257, 526852)
        AND a.country = 'US';  --If you want to filter on country = US
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I select multiple columns from the publications table?

Comment: You can add columns by using `, p.columnname`. Updated my answer to add publications column from Publications table.